# Postgresql don't fully ignore stop words

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Is there a way to use Postgres Full Text Search and have it not fully ignore stop words but rank it lower. like maybe I can generate a ts_vector of only the stop words and add it to ranking with a lower rank. 
For example I would like to be able to have something like "This is how you lose.." and be able to search "this is how" and have a match come up.

my initial thought was to make a dictionary that didn't ignore stop words and in the rank have that be weighted less is this really stupid

Answer (score 0):

For text as short as in our example, I wonder if pg_trgm might not be a better choice than FTS.

Your idea isn't stupid, but it might be a lot of work.  It is just some SQL commands to make it not use the stop words, but implementing your custom ranking function to deweight them is probably not simple.  Perhaps you could just use the 3-argument form of [setweight](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-textsearch.html), with all stop words stuffed into the 3rd argument, to deweight them. And then use one of the built-in ranking functions.  I would at least give that a try, before delving into a completely custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing but if your main goal is:

> ... I would like to be able to have something like "This is how you lose.." and be able to search "this is how" and have a match come up.

Then I suggest to you to use PostgreSQL phrase search.

In your specific example you can search the exact phrase "this is how" in your text "This is how you lose":

```
SELECT to_tsvector('This is how you lose') @@ phraseto_tsquery('this is how');
 ?column? 
----------
 true
```

But if you search for a different phrase (ex: "this as") you would have no match:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('This is how you lose') @@ phraseto_tsquery('this how');
 ?column? 
----------
 false
```

You can find more info and examples in [PostgreSQL Full-text search documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-MATCHING) .

#### Update

[View the queries in action on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnzuiY4UpNHPvcuPQnUeNu/1)

Comment: when I do this I get false and a notice that the query only contains stop words hence why I'm pretty sure I cant use this. My goal is to be able to use the ranking function to get ranks to don't fully ignore stop words but deweigth them

Comment: In your question your wrote an example of search that I used to show you how to use the phrase search in FTS so it's not clear how it not work for you.
I see you are new to StackOverflow so I suggest to you to rephrase your question to make clearer witch is your final goal with more than one data example.

Comment: I mean it didn't work by I copied the first example you gave me and I got false not true

Comment: I added a link to DB fiddle in my answer so you can see queries in action.

Comment: So I looked as at your DBfiddle and the thing is that your to_tsvector doesn't ignore stop words so its not the phrase that makes the query show up it's that you don't ignore stop words(standard behaviour)  in the first place